# Base Entity class for the sake of ID in EF Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Does it makes sense to introduce an abstract `IdableEntity` base class, that has a `public Guid Id { get; set;}` property, and then derive all my entities from it, so I don't have to add key field to each one of them? Will I face any pitfalls if I do in theory?

I used to never do this since my DbContext model was rather simple and consisted of a few classes. Now I am designing a large entity number model that may benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking from experience of this exact thing - yes it makes sense. Note that this EF base class doesn't have to be the heirarchical root though - it could inherit from a base class that implements things like [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx), [IChangeTracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ichangetracking.aspx), etc. So your inheritance chain would look like this:

> *BaseDataClass* <- *BaseEFDataObject* <- [actual EF entities]